# Is it possible for time on Earth to randomly stop?

Tags: physics

On the Glitch in the Matrix subreddit, there are many examples of time stopping.

Here is [an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/Glitch_in_the_Matrix/comments/3034ed/the_world_stopped_for_12_seconds_biggest_matrix/):

> Something felt really weird, my parents were like frozen up (not moving completely) my dad had the mouth open and my mom a really weird gesture, my brother and I just saw them for a second or so completely weird out, after talking to them they moved and seemed normal. Immediately after I turned to my side and the car parallel to our lane about 10 ft away seemed to also be frozen up, like when as a kids we played statues and stayed frozen in awkward body positions. My parents by now “unfrozen” just opened their mouth completely surprise, I looked back and about 10 cars in all directions were also frozen even in the middle of the intersection. My window was down and it was a windy day, but I can swear even the air stopped.

I'm not sure what to think of this, I can't seem to find any news reports of time momentarily stopping (and multiple people experienced this at once, such as in the linked example).

Comment: Time stopped for everything, except a couple of observers??

Comment: @hdhondt time stopped for everyone in the area, except for the person who posted the story, his parents, and his brother, who was also in the car with him.

Comment: No, his parents were frozen too, so there was just the two observers.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I read the story last night, so my memory of it's a little fuzzy, I do remember his parents exclaimed something along the lines of ''what was that?'' when they became unfrozen.

Answer (score 20):

This story was posted by a Reddit user called [borderjumper123](https://www.reddit.com/user/borderjumper123/).

Borderjumper123 has also posted first-person accounts of:

- A girlfriend reporting two version of him: [*Evil Doppelganger Matrix Glitch?*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Glitch_in_the_Matrix/comments/36f6oh/evil_doppelganger_matrix_glitch/)
- Seeing a ghost in a cemetery: [*The most gorgeous apparition.*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thetruthishere/comments/30yyyy/the_most_gorgeous_apparition/)
- His mother seeing a floating humanoid: [comment](https://www.reddit.com/user/borderjumper123/)

So, we are presented with a choice. Do we accept that:

1. this random reddit user (and his family) have encountered an astonishing array of multiple examples of very rare (read: nonexistent) paranormal activity, that violate the most trusted [laws of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), but with no evidence to present except his word?
2. this random reddit user likes to partake in the age-old practice of [making up ghost stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_story)?

[Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) would suggest the latter is the one to provisionally accept, until some actual evidence is provided.

Comment: Interesting findings!