# Is the Glitch In the Matrix subreddit on Reddit real stories?

Tags: physics, social-media

Here is the subreddit

reddit.com/r/glitch_in_the_matrix

Here is a fairly recent example of a story posted to that subreddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/Glitch_in_the_Matrix/comments/qdainf/awoke_in_a_world_where_covid_doesnt_exist/

There also exists a similar subreddit, reddit.com/r/glitchinthematrix which has pictures and photos of things that look like glitches. However, it seems this is being played for laughs.

Something that the stories on the former subreddit have in common is;

- The stories are incompatible with the laws of physics - such as seeing people, cars, and other things vanish before their eyes, or seeing someone teleport from one end of the room to the other.
- Multiple eyewitnesses
- A lot of the stories posted read similarly to the miracles described in religious texts.

Do the stories have any basis in reality?

Comment: Are you asking question about a subredit or a claim on that subredit?

Comment: Related, as it's about another story from that subreddit: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/45868/39658 I believe we've had other similar questions as well.

Comment: This is way too broad. We can't investigate every single story to find out if any of them are true. You can pick one ( a notable one) and ask about that. Do not confuse "there were multiple eye-witnesses" with "one single anonymous person on the Internet claims there were multiple eye-witnesses".

Comment: There is a simple explanation, in that the supposed event occurred when the subject *dreamed* that they had woken up. Please see [**false awakening**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_awakening).

Answer (score 3):

In the case of the linked story, the [OP provided an update](https://www.reddit.com/r/Glitch_in_the_Matrix/comments/qdainf/comment/hhn7e8s/):

> So I talked to a coworker I trust. He said I was acting normal as always. But seemed a little confused and he said I was pale and looked scared. Which I can remember I was freaked the hell out. He said I asked him what's going on with covid. He said he asked me what I was talking about, and then he said I told him I don't feel good and then left work.
>
> All of this which I perfectly remember so it confirms I wasn't dreaming or imagining things. Now I'm really freaked out. Because the possibility of parallel universes actually being real is now extremely high on my believe list lol.

Since a coworker in this universe where COVID exists remembers the exchange, what grounds is there to believe it happened in a different universe (even if it didn't convince OP)?

As for the other stories, they'd have to be addressed on a case by case basis. For many of them, considering the mostly anonymous nature of Reddit, I suspect there aren't enough details to determine what really happened.